# Search with PHP inside MongoDB

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

Im trying many days now to select data from this db
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QA34L.jpg

I want to print for example all comments
echo $comment['username']." | ";  \ Alex | Alex

My php code so far:

```
    [![$m= new MongoDB\Client ("mongodb://127.0.0.1/");
    $db = $m->stores;
    $collection = $db->storeinfo;][1]][1] 
    $storez = $collection->find(array("Products.pTHUMBNAIL" => $pThumb));
    $o=1;
    $afm=array();
    foreach ($storez as $stor) {
        $afm[$o] = $stor['AFM'];

        $record = $collection->findOne(array(
            "AFM" => $afm[$o],"Products.pTHUMBNAIL" => $pThumb));
        foreach ($record['Products'] as $pro){
            if($pThumb == $pro['pTHUMBNAIL']){
                echo $temp = $pro['pID']." ";
                foreach($pro as $pro1['pCOMMENTS']) {
                    foreach($pro1 as $com['Comment']) {
                        var_dump($com['Comment']);
                        /*
                        foreach($com as $comment) {
                            echo $comment['username'];
                        }
                        */
                }              
                }
            }
        }

        $o += 1;
    }
```

It seems that i just cannot find the correct foreach to loop through my Comment array

var_dump output:

```
099360111/1 object(MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId)#55 (1) { ["oid"]=> string(24) "6003403a695900000c002649" } string(11) "099360111/1" string(9) "Old Skool" string(2) "75" string(4) "Vans" string(25) "Leather and textile upper" string(2) "44" string(18) "Men/Shoes/Trainers" string(52) "http://127.0.0.1/pricedoc/assets/img/products/p1.jpg" string(1) "7" object(MongoDB\Model\BSONArray)#65 (1) { ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)#10 (1) { ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=> array(1) { ["Comment"]=> object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)#73 (1) { ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=> array(4) { ["username"]=> string(4) "Alex" ["date"]=> object(MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime)#45 (1) { ["milliseconds"]=> string(13) "1611028053000" } ["text"]=> string(21) "1st comment from user" ["rating"]=> string(1) "4" } } } } } } 099360666/1 object(MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId)#44 (1) { ["oid"]=> string(24) "6006563a3f1c0000c80034a8" } string(11) "099360666/1" string(12) "old school 2" string(2) "50" string(4) "Vans" string(11) "black/white" string(8) "42,43,43" string(18) "Men/Shoes/Trainers" string(52) "http://127.0.0.1/pricedoc/assets/img/products/p1.jpg" string(1) "6" object(MongoDB\Model\BSONArray)#79 (1) { ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)#7 (1) { ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=> array(1) { ["Comment"]=> object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)#39 (1) { ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=> array(4) { ["username"]=> string(4) "Alex" ["date"]=> object(MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime)#68 (1) { ["milliseconds"]=> string(13) "1611028089000" } ["text"]=> string(21) "1st comment from user" ["rating"]=> string(1) "4" } } } } [1]=> object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)#78 (1) { ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=> array(1) { ["Comment"]=> object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)#77 (1) { ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=> array(4) { ["username"]=> string(4) "Alex" ["date"]=> object(MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime)#76 (1) { ["milliseconds"]=> string(13) "1611030745000" } ["text"]=> string(8) "good!!!!" ["rating"]=> string(1) "5" } } } } } }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?
After `echo $temp = $pro['pID']." ";`

```
foreach($pro['pCOMMENTS'] as $comments) {
    foreach ($comments['Comment'] as $comment) {
        echo $comment['text'];
    }
}
```

You used foreach() bad: the index should be added to the first parameter, not in the 'as' part.
Also it helps if you use more clear variable names. That doesn't take too much, but makes it more readable and easy to debug.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the echo dosent work as expected. echo $comment['text']; dosent work at all so i change it to echo $comment; and it returns me a string "Alex16110280530001st comment from user4" so i cant even explode the string because i dont now where every field ends (username,date,text, rating). Do you have any ideas to parse only one field? example only Comment.text ?

Comment: i figured it out. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

After echo $temp = $pro['pID']." ";

```
foreach($pro['pCOMMENTS'] as $comments) {     
  foreach($comments as $comment) {          
    echo $comment['text'];     
  }  
}
```